Jboss Not Recognizing Modified Hibernate Named-Native-Query After Build
I am working with Hibernate ORM framework, and occasionally, when I modify a named-native-query, the build is successful, but the query is not recognized by the JBoss server/JVM. It seems as though the query XML tag is being parsed as blank. This behavior is quite strange, as there’s no obvious issue upon inspection.
The query appears correctly in the code and even when I extract the EAR file, the query is visible. However, when the application runs, the output of the query returns nothing.
Here are the details of Eclipse version:
Eclipse Version:
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520
Below is xsd
<entity-mappings
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"> 

